# How do I replace the go to statement?

Tags: c++

I'm rather new to coding and right now I am working on a assignment where the user is given three options. 
1. Add data
2. View data
3. Quit
My code now includes both switch statement and goto statement and from what I understand this is bad practice. So my question is, how can I replace there and with what? 
Some of this code is in swedish but the options is as stated above. 
Any help appriciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int choice;
int c=0;
double percentage[100];
int menyVal() //Funktion som skriver ut meny
{
    cout<<"V\x84nligen v\x84lj ett av f\x94ljande alternativ f\x94r att forts\x84tta."<<endl;
    cout<<"1 L\x84gg till kandidat och antal r\x94ster."<<endl;
    cout<<"2 Se insamlad data."<<endl;
    cout<<"3 Avsluta."<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    return choice;

}
class Products
{
public:
    string name;
    int vote;
    Products();

};
Products::Products()
{
    string name = "";
    int vote = 0;
}
int main()
{
    Products arr[100];
    cout<<"V\x84lkommen till valr\x84kning."<<endl<<endl;
    begin:
    menyVal();


    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout<<"Du har valt att l\x84gga till r\x94st-data."<<endl<<endl;
        for(int i = (1+c) ; i <= 100 ; i++)
         {
             if(i>100)
             {
                 cout<<"Du har n\x86tt max antal i index."<<endl;
             }

             else
             {

                  cout<<"Skriv in namnet p\x86 kandidat nr"<<i<<"."<<endl;
                  cin>>arr[i].name;
                  if(arr[i].name==arr[i-1].name)
                  {
                    cout<<"Kandidater kan inte heta exakt samma sak."<<endl;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                  cout<<"Skriv in antal r\x94ster "<<arr[i].name<<" fick."<<endl;
                  cin>>arr[i].vote;
                  cout<<"Datan \x84r nu inlagd i index."<<endl<<endl;
                  c++;

                  }
                  goto begin;
                  }
             }
        break;

        case 2:

            cout<<"Du har valt att se all inmatad data."<<endl<<endl;
            if(c==0)
                {
                    cout<<"Index \x84r just nu tomt."<<endl<<endl;
                    goto begin;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"|Kandidat Nr|"<<"\t"<<"|Namn|"<<"\t"<<"|Antal r\x94ster.|"<<"\t"<<"|R\x94ster i %.|"<<endl;
                    for(int i =1 ; i <=c ; i++)
                {
                    cout<<i<<"\t\t";
                    cout<<arr[i].name<<"\t\t";
                    cout<<arr[i].vote<<"\t\t";
                    cout<<arr[i].vote<<"%"<<endl;


                }
                    goto begin;
                }

        break;

        case 3:

             cout<<"Du har valt att avsluta programmet."<<endl;
                   return 0;


}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can replace that `goto` with a `do...while` or `while` statement for instance.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to make your code more readable. The first step is to fix your indentation and spacing. This is roughly how it should look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int choice;
int c=0;
double percentage[100];

int menyVal() //Funktion som skriver ut meny
{
    cout<<"V\x84nligen v\x84lj ett av f\x94ljande alternativ f\x94r att forts\x84tta."<<endl;
    cout<<"1 L\x84gg till kandidat och antal r\x94ster."<<endl;
    cout<<"2 Se insamlad data."<<endl;
    cout<<"3 Avsluta."<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    return choice;
}

class Products
{
public:
    string name;
    int vote;
    Products();
};

Products::Products()
{
    string name = "";
    int vote = 0;
}

int main()
{
    Products arr[100];
    cout<<"V\x84lkommen till valr\x84kning."<<endl<<endl;
    begin:
    menyVal();

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        cout<<"Du har valt att l\x84gga till r\x94st-data."<<endl<<endl;
        for(int i = (1+c) ; i <= 100 ; i++)
        {
            if(i>100)
            {
                cout<<"Du har n\x86tt max antal i index."<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Skriv in namnet p\x86 kandidat nr"<<i<<"."<<endl;
                cin>>arr[i].name;
                if(arr[i].name==arr[i-1].name)
                {
                    cout<<"Kandidater kan inte heta exakt samma sak."<<endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"Skriv in antal r\x94ster "<<arr[i].name<<" fick."<<endl;
                    cin>>arr[i].vote;
                    cout<<"Datan \x84r nu inlagd i index."<<endl<<endl;
                    c++;
                }
                goto begin;
            }
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        cout<<"Du har valt att se all inmatad data."<<endl<<endl;
        if(c==0)
        {
            cout<<"Index \x84r just nu tomt."<<endl<<endl;
            goto begin;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"|Kandidat Nr|"<<"\t"<<"|Namn|"<<"\t"<<"|Antal r\x94ster.|"<<"\t"<<"|R\x94ster i %.|"<<endl;
            for(int i =1 ; i <=c ; i++)
            {
                cout<<i<<"\t\t";
                cout<<arr[i].name<<"\t\t";
                cout<<arr[i].vote<<"\t\t";
                cout<<arr[i].vote<<"%"<<endl;
            }
            goto begin;
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        cout<<"Du har valt att avsluta programmet."<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The next step is to identify exactly what paths you can take through the code. Of course, in this case, it's about the code between the `begin` label and the end of the switch. So let's simplify this part by keeping only the control flow:

```
begin:
menyVal(); // set choice

switch (choice)
{
case 1:
    for(int i = (1+c) ; i <= 100 ; i++)
    {
        if(i>100)
        {
            // [A]
        }
        else
        {
            if(arr[i].name==arr[i-1].name)
            {
                // ...
            }
            else
            {
                // ...
            }
            goto begin;
        }
    }
    break;

case 2:
    if(c==0)
    {
        goto begin;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i =1 ; i <=c ; i++)
        {
            // ...
        }
        goto begin;
    }
    break;

case 3:
    return 0;
}
```

Notice how, in case 1, the `[A]` part is not reachable since it requires both `i<=100` and `i>100`. Therefore the code always goes in the `else` part, which ends in `goto begin`, so the loop is useless as well (it can be replaced by something like `int i = (1+c); if (i <= 100) { ... }`), and it always ends with `goto begin`. Notice how both paths in case 2 also lead to `goto begin`. Only case 3 leads to something else, presumably continuing the program (here, by simply exiting). So in the end, the control flow really looks like this:

```
menyVal();

while (choice != 3) {
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        int i = (1+c);
        if (i <= 100)
        {
            // ...
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        if(c==0)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i =1 ; i <=c ; i++)
            {
                // ...
            }
            // ...
        }
        break;
    }
    menyVal();
}
```

Moreover, you might want to make functions out of your cases, so you can make the control flow more readable. Something like that:

```
while (menyVal() != 3) {
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        doA();
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        doB();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! I changed the goto to a do while-loop and made most of the main into functions. This made it easier to read and I could then change the switch to if statements. This is how it looks now.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int choice;
int c=0;
class Election //Klass som sätter variabler för array
{
public:
    string name;
    int vote;
    Election();
};
Election::Election() //Default construktor
{
    string name = "";
    int vote = 0;
}
int menyVal(); //Funktion som skriver ut meny
void setData (Election *arr);
void printData (Election *arr);
void printWinner (Election *arr);

int main()
{
    cout<<"V\x84lkommen till valr\x84kning."<<endl<<endl;

    Election arr[100];
    menyVal();
    do{
    if (choice==1)
    {
        setData(arr);
        continue;
    }
    else if (choice==2)
    {
        printData(arr);
        continue;
    }
    else if (choice==3)
    {
        printWinner(arr);
        continue;
    }
    else if (choice==4)
    {
        cout<<"Du har valt att avsluta programmet."<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Ogiltigt val. F\x94rs\x94k igen."<<endl;
        continue;

    } while (menyVal() != 4);
return 0;
}

int menyVal()//Funktion som skriver ut meny
{
    cout<<"V\x84nligen v\x84lj ett av f\x94ljande alternativ f\x94r att forts\x84tta."<<endl;
    cout<<"1. L\x84gg till kandidat och antal r\x94ster."<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Se insamlad data."<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Se vinnaren av valet."<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Avsluta programmet."<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    return choice;
}

void setData (Election *arr)
{

            cout<<"Du har valt att l\x84gga till r\x94st-data."<<endl<<endl;
             for(int i = (1+c) ; i <= 100 ; i++){
             if(i>100)
             {
                 cout<<"Du har n\x86tt max antal i index."<<endl;
             }
             else
             {
                  cout<<"Skriv in namnet p\x86 kandidat nr"<<i<<"."<<endl;
                  cin>>arr[i].name;
                  if(arr[i].name==arr[i-1].name)
                  {
                    cout<<"Kandidater kan inte heta exakt samma sak."<<endl;
                    break;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                  cout<<"Skriv in antal r\x94ster "<<arr[i].name<<" fick."<<endl;
                  cin>>arr[i].vote;
                      while (cin.fail())
                      {
                        cout<<"R\x94ster m\x86ste anges i heltal."<<endl;
                        cin.clear();
                        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
                        cout<<"Skriv in antal r\x94ster "<<arr[i].name<<" fick."<<endl;
                        cin>>arr[i].vote;
                       }
                         cout<<"Datan \x84r nu inlagd i index."<<endl<<endl;
                  c++;
                  }
                 break;
              }
        }
}
void printData (Election *arr)
{
    int total_vote=0;
    for(int i=1 ;i<=c ;i++)
    {
        total_vote=total_vote+arr[i].vote;
    }
            cout<<"Du har valt att se all inmatad data."<<endl<<endl;
                if(c==0)
                {
                    cout<<"Index \x84r just nu tomt."<<endl<<endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"|Kandidat Nr|"<<"\t"<<"|Namn|"<<"\t"<<"|Antal r\x94ster.|"<<"\t"<<"|R\x94ster i %.|"<<endl;
                    for(int i =1 ; i <=c ; i++)
                {
                    cout<<i<<"\t\t";
                    cout<<arr[i].name<<"\t\t";
                    cout<<arr[i].vote<<"\t\t";
                    cout<<(arr[i].vote*100)/total_vote<<"%"<<endl;
                }

                }
}
void printWinner (Election *arr)
{
    int max=INT_MIN,count=0;
    int index[100]={0};

    for(int i=1; i<=c; i++){
        if(arr[i].vote>max)
        {
            max=arr[i].vote;
        }
    }

    for(int i=1; i<=c; i++){
        if(arr[i].vote==max)
        {
            index[count]=i;
            count++;
        }
    }

    if(count==1)
        cout<<"Vinnaren av valet \x84r "<<arr[index[count-1]].name<<"!"<<endl<<endl;
    else{
        cout<<"Valet slutade oavgjort mellan ";
        for(int i=0;i<count-1;i++)
            cout<<arr[index[i]].name<<", ";
        cout<<arr[index[count-1]].name<<endl;

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need any of the `continue`s in your do-while. Also note that the `else` lacks curly braces (the indentation implies they should be there).